# Replace image in a shape, not add a new one

Tags: vb.net, image, vsto, powerpoint, shapes

I have a VSTO written in VB.NET and want to maximize a selected image to the background. Documents tell me to remove the old shape and add a new one with `AddPicture`, but I have a template that includes image shapes already there and `AddPicture` puts the image in one of those shapes already there.

To prevent images from landing in the wrong shape I really just want to replace the original image with the resized one.

This is what I have:

```
dim src as PowerPoint.Shape = PowerPoint.Selection.ShapeRange.Item(1)
src.Export(file1, PowerPoint.PpShapeFormat.ppShapeFormatPNG)
dim img as Image = BitMap.FromFile(file1)
```

Then some image magic, and then:

```
img.Save(file2, PowerPoint.PpShapeFormat.ppShapeFormatPNG)

Dim _S As PowerPoint.Slide = ppApp.ActiveWindow.View.Slide
Dim _P As PowerPoint.Shape = _S.Shapes.AddPicture2(file2, MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoTrue, 0, 0, _W, _H)
```

But that puts the image in the wrong template-shape.

Is there a way to actually replace the image in a shape without adding a new shape?

Comment: have you tried [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/39eb7cf4-2e85-4010-8e6a-10da20b352f7/replacing-changing-the-pictures-in-powerpoint-presentation?forum=isvvba)?

Comment: That's exactly the point.. All methods seem to delete the old shape and insert a new one with a type Image. But because I have a template that has addtional shapeholders, the AddPicture method inserts the image in one of those which I absolutely don't want. I'm looking for a way to replace the actual image inside an existing shape.

Answer (score 2):

You can't insert an image inside a shape, only (in some cases) inside a placeholder, and you've mentioned that you specifically don't want to do that.

You can use an image to *fill* a shape, but unless you don't mind the image getting distorted, the aspect ratios of the image and the shape must match.

Suggestion:  before adding the new image/shape, iterate through all the shapes on the slide looking for placeholder shapes. If any placeholder shape is of a type that can contain images (Content, Picture and Clip Art placeholders), fill it with dummy content (a few characters of text for Content, any random picture for the other two). Add your image; since the "image-capable" placeholders are already filled, the image will be added as a new shape.  Then delete each of the shapes you've added dummy content to. When you delete a placeholder that has content, the content gets deleted and leaves the original empty placeholder behind.

Comment: actually that's exactly what i do manually now :) tedious and frustrating if I forget one. I was hoping that you can kind of replace an image but that sounds impossible. I'll give that a try, see if a shapeholder is empty, fill it, paste/delete image, empty said placeholders..

Comment: ok, got some time left to try this again but when i reread your answer won't i run into the exact same problem? how do i put dummy content in image-capable shapes? that's kind of the problem here. if i could do that, i'd put my image in the shape that i need, not put dummy images in all the others ;) .. any ideas? sound like a loopy problem this way

Comment: You could add tags to any placeholder you've inserted dummy content into: oSh.Tags.Add "Dummy", "Y"  then after you've added your real image, iterate through each shape on the slide (backwards, from Shapes.Count to 1 Step -1) and If oSh.Tags("Dummy") = "Y" Then oSh.Delete

Comment: Hm, that still feels like a chicken-and-egg problem. I've now tried to 

    `for each sh in _selection.Shapes 
      If sh IsNot _OrgShape Then
        sh.Cut()
        _selection.Shapes.Paste()
      End If
    End For`

In an attempt to find the Original container and paste the new image in that placeholder. But somehow the order of shapes doesn't seem to change as expected and the image now appears rather random in placeholders.. So, i'm still looking for an elegant solution :(